# Why can't I save a value for Inherited Project Property Sheets?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, propertysheet

I'm trying to add Inherited Project Property Sheets to the configuration for a project.

I paste in the string

`..\..\vs\library.vsprops;..\..\vs\debug.vsprops;..\..\vs\platformx64.vsprops`

And click Apply/OK. As soon as I do the property is cleared (most visible when clicking Apply). What is going on?